# How to get the data after parsing json created using nlohmann json

Tags: c++11, json-deserialization, jsonserializer, nlohmann-json

I have a requirement to store two structure namely one and two in Json in following format, and then parse this JSON and store the data back to those structure object.

```
{ "One",{
            { "Value1", one.Value1() },
        }
        },
{ "Two",{
            { "Value1", two.Value1() },
            { "Value2", two.Value2() }
        }
        },
```

I am able to store the data in json file, but when I read it back to get the structure values , I am getting following error:

```
1>c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(72): error C3867: 'One::Value1': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(72): error C2672: 'nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<std::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::get_to': no matching overloaded function found
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=uint8_t
1>          ]
1>c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(87): error C2672: 'nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<std::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::get': no matching overloaded function found
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=uint8_t
1>          ]
1>c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(87): error C2783: 'unknown-type nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<std::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::get(void) noexcept': could not deduce template argument for '__formal'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=uint8_t
1>          ]
1>  c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\nlohmann\json.hpp(20950): note: see declaration of 'nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<std::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::get'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=uint8_t
1>          ]
1>c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(87): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::basic_json<std::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_2::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::get(void) noexcept(<expr>) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=uint8_t
1>          ]
1>  c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(87): note: With the following template arguments:
1>  c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(87): note: 'ValueTypeCV=One'
1>  c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(87): note: 'ValueType=One'
1>c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(87): error C2512: 'One': no appropriate default constructor available
1>  c:\users\212506\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6.cpp(35): note: see declaration of 'One'
```

Code that i am working is :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <initializer_list>

#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
using nlohmann::json;

class Two
{
public:
    Two() :m_Value1(0), m_Value2(0)
    {}

    Two(int val1, int val2) :
        m_Value1(val1), m_Value2(val2)
    {
    }

    int& Value1()
    {
        return m_Value1;
    }
    int& Value2()
    {
        return m_Value2;
    }

public:
    int m_Value1;
    int m_Value2;
};

class One
{
public:
    One() : m_Value1_1(0)
    {}
    One(int val1) : m_Value1_1(val1)
    {
    }
    int& Value1()
    {
        return m_Value1_1;
    }

public:
    int m_Value1_1;
};

std::string ToJsonString(One &one, Two &two)
{
    nlohmann::json j =
    {
        { "One",{
            { "Value1", one.Value1() },
        }
        },
        { "Two",{
            { "Value1", two.Value1() },
            { "Value2", two.Value2() }
        }
        },
    };

    std::cout << j.dump(4) << std::endl;
    std::string str = j.dump(4);
    return str;
}

void from_json(const json& j, One& one) {
    j.at("Value1").get_to(one.Value1());
}

void from_json(const json& j, Two& two) {
    j.at("Value1").get_to(two.Value1());
    j.at("Value2").get_to(two.Value2());
}

void ToObjectsOne(std::string json, One &one1, Two &two1)
{
    nlohmann::json data;
    try
    {
        data = nlohmann::json::parse(json);
    }
    catch (nlohmann::json::exception& exception)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception[" << exception.what() << "]";
    }

    one1 = data["One"].get<One>();
    two1 = data["Two"].get<Two>();
}


int main()
{
    One one(10);
    Two two(10, 20);

    std::string jsonStr = ToJsonString(one, two);

    One one1;
    Two two1;
    ToObjectsOne(jsonStr, one1, two1);

    std::cout << one1.m_Value1_1<<std::endl;
    std::cout << two1.m_Value1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << two1.m_Value2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know whether can we use get this way:

```
One one = data["One"].get<One>();
```

if not then how should i get the values from the json for both the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`nlohmann::basic_json::get`](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/get/)  requires the object to be default constructible and copy constructible so you need to add a default constructor. You should also supply a reference to the variable you want to `get_to`:

```cpp
class One {
public:
    One() = default;                          // add
    One(int val1) : m_Value1_1(val1) {}

    int Value1() const { return m_Value1_1; }
    int& Value1() { return m_Value1_1; }      // return int&

private:
    int m_Value1_1{};
};
```

You also need to call `one.Value1` since it's a function:

```cpp
void from_json(const json& j, One& one) {
    j.at("Value1").get_to(one.Value1());
//                                  ^^
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ted, I updated the code as suggested and it works for me now. I am using this nlohmann packages for the first time, so have a small query as well if you can answer those as well: 1.) is filling object of One class as following is right thing to do.                                
        `one1 = data["One"].get<One>();
 two1 = data["Two"].get<Two>();`   Also i am not having any set method in my class, still i see correct values updated for my object. am i doing anything wrong here `j.at("Value1").get_to(one.Value1());`

Comment: @user2094814 _"it works for me now"_ - great! You're weclome! Yes, you uses of `get` looks correct.